# Find the radius of convergence of the power series representing $\frac{1}{2-z}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Find the radius of convergence of the power series representing $\frac{1}{2-z}$, about $z=0$, without calculating the power series itself.

I have also been given the power series representation and determined the radius of convergence to be equal to 2. However I am stuck on how to calculate this without looking at the power series.

Comment: Hopefully it is clear from $$\frac{1}{2-z} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-z/2}$$

Comment: What does it means "I am stuck"? What did you try?

Comment: Thankyou, I knew some algebraic manipulation was probably in order! So we see $\frac{1}{1-z/2}$ has radius of convergence equal to 2. And since we are multiplying the power series by a constant it doesn't affect the radius of convergence?

Comment: You have tagged the question complex-analysis, so presumably you know some. An alternative is to look at the distance between 0 (your power series is about 0) and the nearest pole, which is at $z=2$.

Comment: So outside of the open disc centred at 0 with radius 2, the power series no longer converges as it is no longer analytic in such a neighbourhood?